# Add two objects into one json_encode in php

Tags: php, json

My try is to make an pagination and thats my ajax request page:

```
while ($file = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $arrayFetch[] = [

            'id'   => $file['id'],
            'name' => $file['name']   
        ];

    $lastId = $file['lastId'];
}

// For simplify: Here is another query code for get the the result of $count

$count = $query->rowCount();
```

So, I have now the variables `$arrayFetch` and `$count`.

UPDATE:

My actually code for json_encode is:

```
echo '{"user":'.json_encode($arrayFetch).'}';
```

The output is:

```
{"user":[{ "id":1,"name":"toby"},....]}
```

what I want is to add an second object like this:

```
{"user":[{ "id":1,"name":"toby"},....]},

{"pagination":[{ "count":10" }]} // THIS
```

That don't work, it's only an example to show what I try to archive:

```
echo '{"user":'.json_encode($arrayFetch).'},{ "pagination": [{ "count" : '.$count.' }] ';
```

Comment: That's fine, but understand that a JSON array without the square brackets is not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'user'=>$arrayFetch,
    'count'=>$count,
));
```

Comment: You also should send json header. header("Content-type:application/Jason")

Comment: Thanks men... you got it! (The `header` are not necessary).. :)

Comment: Correction: header('Content-Type: application/json'); No, not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't get you but...

```
$arrayFetch['user'][] = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "name" => $name
            );
```

Is it what you want?